SQL Trigger sum rows when some value is NULL
I want to sum 3 rows but when value1 is NULL i want to skip it to sum all other rows:
CREATE TRIGGER `sum_total_test_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `test`  
FOR EACH ROW  
BEGIN  
 IF (NEW.value1 IS NULL) THEN  
 SET NEW.Total = (NEW.value2 + NEW.value3);  
 ELSE  
 SET NEW.Total = (NEW.value1 + NEW.value2 + NEW.value3);  
END IF;  

Example of Expected values on Total row
value1  value2  value3  Total
5       6       6       17
2       5       4       11
NULL    5       4       9

ERROR: #1064 - Something is wrong in your syntax near '' in line 5
Thanks for your help.
I expect to have a correct syntax

Which dbms are you using? (Seems like a proprietary syntax attempt.)

i am using mysql

Giving your columns names like “row1” is really confusing

true... i edit it and give another names...

Your error means that you forget about DELIMITER reassigning.

If this were the complete code for the trigger,  the keyword END had certainly been left out.

CREATE TRIGGER `sum_total_test_before_insert` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `test`  
FOR EACH ROW  
SET NEW.Total = COALESCE(NEW.value1, 0) + NEW.value2 + NEW.value3;  

But I'd prefer to make Total column generated one. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html
